# Printing Lyrics to a Nursery Rhyme (Java)

Tags: java

I'm just trying to have my code print out the lyrics to this nursery rhyme. I have absolutely no idea why only the last stanza prints out correctly.

This is my code:

```
public class ThisOldMan
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      verse1();
      verse2();
      verse3();
      verse4();
      verse5();
      verse6();
      verse7();
      verse8();
      verse9();
      verse10();
   }

   static void thisOldManHePlayed()
   {
      System.out.print("This old man, he played ");
   }

   static void hePlayedNickNack()
   {
      System.out.print("He played nick-nack ");
   }


   static void withANickNickPaddyWhack()
   {
      System.out.println("With a nick-nack paddy-whack, give a dog a bone, ");
      System.out.println("This old man came running home.");
   }

   static void verse1()
   {
      thisOldManHePlayed();
      System.out.print("1.");
      System.out.println();
      hePlayedNickNack();
      System.out.print("on my drum; ");
      System.out.println();
      withANickNickPaddyWhack();
   }

   static void verse2()
   {
      thisOldManHePlayed();
      System.out.print("2.");
      System.out.println();
      hePlayedNickNack();
      System.out.print("on my shoe; ");
      System.out.println();
      withANickNickPaddyWhack();
   }

   static void verse3()
   {
      thisOldManHePlayed();
      System.out.print("3.");
      System.out.println();
      hePlayedNickNack();
      System.out.print("on my knee; ");
      System.out.println();
      withANickNickPaddyWhack();
   }

   static void verse4()
   {
      thisOldManHePlayed();
      System.out.print("4.");
      System.out.println();
      hePlayedNickNack();
      System.out.print("on my door; ");
      System.out.println();
      withANickNickPaddyWhack();
   }

   static void verse5()
   {
      thisOldManHePlayed();
      System.out.print("5.");
      System.out.println();
      hePlayedNickNack();
      System.out.print("on my hive; ");
      System.out.println();
      withANickNickPaddyWhack();
   }

   static void verse6()
   {
      thisOldManHePlayed();
      System.out.print("6.");
      System.out.println();
      hePlayedNickNack();
      System.out.print("on my sticks; ");
      System.out.println();
      withANickNickPaddyWhack();
   }

   static void verse7()
   {
      thisOldManHePlayed();
      System.out.print("7.");
      System.out.println();
      hePlayedNickNack();
      System.out.print("up in heaven; ");
      System.out.println();
      withANickNickPaddyWhack();
   }

   static void verse8()
   {
      thisOldManHePlayed();
      System.out.print("8.");
      System.out.println();
      hePlayedNickNack();
      System.out.print("on my gate; ");
      System.out.println();
      withANickNickPaddyWhack();
   }

   static void verse9()
   {
      thisOldManHePlayed();
      System.out.print("9.");
      System.out.println();
      hePlayedNickNack();
      System.out.print("on my spine; ");
      System.out.println();
      withANickNickPaddyWhack();
   }

   static void verse10()
   {
      thisOldManHePlayed();
      System.out.print("10.");
      System.out.println();
      hePlayedNickNack();
      System.out.print("on my hen; ");
      System.out.println();
      withANickNickPaddyWhack();
   }

}
```

This is what it is printing out:

> This old man came running home.
>   This old man came running home.
>   on my hive; With a nick-nack paddy-whack, give a dog a bone, 
>   This old man came running home.
>
> This old man came running home.
>
> This old man, he played 10.
>   This old man came running home.
>   This old man came running home.
>   This old man, he played 3.He played nick-nack on my tree; With a nick-nack paddy-> whack, give a dog a bone, 
>   This old man, he played 5.He played nick-nack on my hive; With a nick-nack paddy-> whack, give a dog a bone,
>
> This old man came running home.
>
> This old man, he played 10.
>   With a nick-nack paddy-whack, give a dog a bone, 
>   He played nick-nack on my drum; 
>   This old man, he played 4.He played nick-nack on my door; With a nick-nack paddy-> whack, give a dog a bone, 
>   This old man, he played 6.He played nick-nack on my sticks; With a nick-nack paddy-whack, give a dog a bone, 
>   This old man, he played 8.He played nick-nack on my gate; With a nick-nack paddy-whack, give a dog a bone, 
>   This old man came running home.
>
> This old man, he played 10.
>   With a nick-nack paddy-whack, give a dog a bone, 
>   With a nick-nack paddy-whack, give a dog a bone, 
>   This old man came running home.
>   This old man, he played 10.
>   He played nick-nack on my hen; 
>   With a nick-nack paddy-whack, give a dog a bone, 
>   This old man came running home.
>   This old man, he played 10.
>   He played nick-nack on my hen; 
>   This old man, he played 2.He played nick-nack on my shoe; With a nick-nack paddy-> whack, give a dog a bone, 
>   This old man, he played 4.He played nick-nack on my door; With a nick-nack paddy-> whack, give a dog a bone,
>
> This old man came running home.
>
> This old man, he played 10.
>   He played nick-nack on my hen; 
>   This old man, he played 2.He played nick-nack on my shoe; With a nick-nack paddy-> whack, give a dog a bone, 
>   This old man came running home.
>   This old man, he played 5.He played nick-nack on my hive; With a nick-nack paddy-> whack, give a dog a bone,
>
> This old man came running home.
>
> This old man, he played 10.
>   He played nick-nack on my hen; 
>   He played nick-nack on my drum; 
>   This old man came running home.
>   This old man, he played 4.He played nick-nack on my door; With a nick-nack paddy-> whack, give a dog a bone, 
>   This old man, he played 6.He played nick-nack on my sticks; With a nick-nack  paddy-whack, give a dog a bone, 
>   This old man, he played 7.He played nick-nack up in heaven; With a nick-nack  paddy-whack, give a dog a bone, 
>   This old man came running home.
>
> This old man, he played 10.
>   He played nick-nack on my hen; 
>   With a nick-nack paddy-whack, give a dog a bone, 
>   This old man came running home.

I have absolutely no idea why everything up until verse 10 is so random! Any advice would be much appreciated!

Comment: It does not seem like that code would produce that output.

Comment: I compiled and ran it, and it works fine for me.

Comment: Works for me too. What environment are you running this in?  The only thing I can think of is that the environment itself is messing with your output.  If this might make any sense at all, try running the code a different way, like right at a command prompt. - btw, I ran your code in IntelliJ on a Mac.

Comment: As with two earlier comments, your code works fine for me as well. Try creating a new project, then paste/run the code in the question. If that works then consider deleting your question because it will serve no useful purpose. However, if it still fails then there you would appear to have an environmental issue, so update your question with more information including O/S, IDE and JDK version.